# Проверка возможности подключения к удалённому хосту

Tags: c#

К сути вопроса, как без `try-catch-finally` проверить, может ли подключиться компьютер к удалённому серверу, без исключений и ошибок?

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 7766);
```

Comment: Непонятно, откуда вообще такое требование у вас появилось? Зачем это нужно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никак.

Любая операция ввода-вывода по своей сути зависит от внешнего мира, а значит, вы не можете рассчитывать на то, что она завершится удачно. Даже если сейчас проверка показывает, что всё в порядке, через миллисекунду уборщица выдернет сетевой кабель, и ваш код не сможет подключиться к удалённому хосту.

Отлова исключений не избежать, смиритесь.